# Robolectric Unit tests with AndroidAnnotations

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

I'm having problems with AndroidAnnotations unit tests using Robolectric.

I got my tests running. But generated class was unable to find any elements that should be included in the view.
Here is my test class. While debugging I can see that "afterSetContentView_" was not able to findViewById.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class MainActivityTest {

private MainActivity activity;
private EditText mTextView;
private Button btnLogin;

 @Before
 public void setup() {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
    mTextView = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
 }
}
```

Here is my activity:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.login)
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@ViewById(R.id.etUserName)
EditText etUerName;

..........
}
```

Here I have updated with my test class

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class) 
@Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18)   

public class LoginActivityTest { 

@Before 
public void setup() {

 Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity_.class).create().get(); 

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the generated classes (MainActivity_) when you want to start an activity with robolectric.

```
Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity_.class).create().get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this. But I got below error message. Any suggestion please                        java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: Without more information I have no suggestion. Stacktrace and code example would help

Comment: I couldn't find any solution for this. When I call LoginActivity_ i got InvocationTargetException. Please see my test class below. Thanks!

    @RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18)
public class LoginActivityTest {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity_.class).create().get();
    }

    }

Comment: `./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` is not the best solution pls remove this. If not already done then switch to robolectric-3.0rc2 and use `RobolectricGradleTestRunner` which will fix manifest and resource resolution. Why `emulateSdk = 18`?

Comment: I doesn't work for me. I removed @Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18) and added @RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class).

WARNING: No manifest file found at ./AndroidManifest.xml.Falling back to the Android OS resources only.
To remove this warning, annotate your test class with @Config(manifest=Config.NONE).

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/view/Window$Callback
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)

Comment: Which operations system do you use? (Windows, Mac, Linux) Did you add your BuildConfig like described at http://robolectric.org/getting-started/

Answer (score 1):

Finally i found the solution. I added below code into my test class and now it works fine. Thanks!

```
@Config(manifest = "app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = 18, reportSdk = 18)
public class LoginActivityTest {

@Before
public void setup() {
Robolectric.buildActivity(LoginActivity_.class).create().get();
    usrName = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    password = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    usrName.setText("su_test@volume.co.uk");
    password.setText("volum3");

}
}
```

Comment: sorry guy but with `"app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"` you will run later or early in some other issues. You didn't answer my last question but you should really follow http://robolectric.org/getting-started/